# Is there a way to get Visual Studio 2010 to support XML Schema 1.1

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, xsd-1.1

So I am working on a bit of a side project that requires an xml schema, which I am quite unfamiliar with.

I want to be able to set the schema to choose between two sets of attributes, which from what I have researched is not directly possible in XSD 1.0, but is apparently a feature of XSD 1.1.

Currently I am using Visual Studio to do my work, and it seems to be stuck in XSD 1.0 mode, which makes sense since XSD 1.1 is apparently a recent development.

My question is, is there a plugin/extension available that can allow me to work with XSD 1.1 in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

No, Microsoft has no products which support XSD 1.1 (or xslt2, or xpath2, or xquery3)

Answer (score 2):

From wikipedia: "XSD 1.1 became a W3C Recommendation in April 2012, which means it is an approved W3C specification." [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29#Version_1.1)

So if it was only recently completed, it is only natural that visual studio does not yet offer support for it. So you are left with the choice of a) writing your app using XSD 1.0, b) Writing your app using XSD 1.1, in the hope that support for it is released before its too late for you. The safer choice would be to stick with XSD 1.0 for now, unless you have solid information on when 1.1 support is released.

Comment: Aye, I had seen that wiki.
Went ahead with 1.0, might come back and change later.
I was kinda stretching hope anyway. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently but if enough of us [vote for it on this MSDN site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/428e8380-32b3-4b5b-894a-044b2bf65e10/xsd-11-support-in-net?forum=netfxbcl) maybe it will happen sooner?

Comment: Good luck with that ;)